# Java error centos 6

Tags: java

I tried installing java and it didn't work I do `java -version` it didnt
work

Please help

```
[root@AvokPvP Avok]# java
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
[root@AvokPvP Avok]#
```

It iwill not work please help

Comment: If `java -version` didn't work, then did you actually successfully install Java? Do you have Java on your path? Run `echo $PATH` and let us know.

Comment: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, `it didn't work` doesn't help us help you.

That said, it looks like your system doesn't have enough memory to create Java's virtual machine - so Java *must* be installed.

I deduced this by reading

1. `Could not reserve enough space for object heap`
2. `Could not create the Java virtual machine.`

You can try shrinking the heap size by specifying the `-Xmx` and `-Xms` arguments.

```
java -Xmx64m -Xms32m
```

Comment: When i do java -version